# Summarize data in Excel as a matrix

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

I have a simple table in Excel like the following one:

[image: source data]

I need to transform it so that it looks like this:

[image: summary matrix]

How can I accomplish this in Excel using pivot table or power pivot (macros excluded)?

Thanks!

Update: In my specific case, the pivot does not need to show grand totals. However there may be other situations where they are.

Comment: Assuming your data starts in Cell A1, in column E use helper column = C2&" With "&D2.. Then you can use Text Value Pivot Table .. See .. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7_YvOpjUBNQ

Comment: Naresh, the helper column does not help unfortunately. However the video you recommended brought me on the right track. Thanks! I'll post below the complete solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best solution I found so far starting from the suggestions I received:

1. Make sure to check the "Add this data to the Data Model" in order to be able to create a new Measure.
   [image: create pivot table with the option "Add this data to the Data Model" checked]
2. Create the new Measure and use the following function:
   [image: Create new Measure with CONCATENATEX function]

   =CONCATENATEX(Table1;Table1[Result] & " with " & Table1[Grade];", ")

Remarks:
The function CONCATENATEX offers the advantage over the funtion VALUES that the pivot table can have grand totals on rows and columns, which by default are enabled when you create a brand new pivot.

Comment: Please edit you remark to clarify. You can add your  comment below the other answer which clarifies it better

Answer (score 0):

Create a pivot table with `Student` on row and `Exam` on columns and add a measure that concatenates `Result` and `Grade`.

```
TextMeasure = VALUES(TableName[Result]) & " with " & VALUES(TableName[Grade])
```

---

Note that this will break for subtotals and grand totals. However, there are ways to fix that.

One way is to do a single value check (and return blank otherwise):

```
TextMeasure =
IF (
    HASONEVALUE(TableName[Result]) && HASONEVALUE (TableName[Grade]),
    VALUES(TableName[Result]) & " with " & VALUES(TableName[Grade])
)
```

A shorter way is to just use `MAX` instead of `VALUES` but this won't have blanks for totals:

```
TextMeasure = MAX(TableName[Result]) & " with " & MAX(TableName[Grade])
```

Comment: Alexis, your solution works only if I remove the grand totals on rows and columns. Otherwise it throws the following error:
"MdxScript(Model) (6,31) Calculation error in measure 'TableName'[TextMeasure]: A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected."

Comment: What is the expected behavior for totals?

Comment: In my specific case, grand totals are not important (I'll update my original post to mention this). However, because the grand totals are active by default as soons as you create a pivot table, the above error message is thrown right away when trying to add the measure using the code you proposed initially, unless one disables the grand totals before adding the measure. Most people don't do this, so they hit the error and ask why...